# How can I detect the new view during touchedMoved in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to detect the new view during touchesMoved when my finger moves aView to bView.  I use touches.first to detect it, but it shows aView even my finger is touching (pushing) bView.
How can I detect which view am I touching (pushing) in touchedMoved?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    print(touch.view) // return aView
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    print(touch.view) // return aView even I'm touching bView from aView during this method
}
```

Comment: From logical point of view you probably want to get through set of touches and detect if it contains any other view but `aView`. Using first implies that you're interested in the first touch that occurred, which is basically `aView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `aView` and `bView` are descendants of the same `superview` and their frames do not intersect, you can use this code:

```
let touchLocation = touch.location(in: superview)
if aView.frame.contains(touchLocation) {
    // touch in aView
} else if bView.frame.contains(touchLocation) {
    // touch in bView
}
```